# Call methods in other HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, ios

I am relatively new to web programming (just started html, javascript, php). I wanted to create a database manager for a website I am building. Now, in ios I would create a .h file called DBManager, with a list og methods I can call, and then import this file in any other .m file and do something like:

```
[DBManager uploadInage: image with completition...];
```

How can I do this for the web?

Comment: not sure if this is what you mean but in php you can add `<?php include_once('functions_file_path.php'); ?>` or require_once instead of include_once, the difference being that if require_once can't include the file then it will halt execution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not a direct equivalent in the languages you mention.
HTML is a markup language and as such does not have funcitons at all.

Javascript and PHP are both [interpreted languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreted_language), which can be used inline in your HTML. You will find that they aren't as structured in some ways as compiled languages like Objective-C. You can use different approaches to structuring your code, but there is no compiler enforcing them.

So for example, you can deploy some Javascript with your HTML which makes a method call, and it doesn't matter if that method was even written yet. As long as it can be found at runtime, it will work.

The same goes for PHP. Nothing will prevent you from writing and deploying your code making any method calls you like. As long as those methods can be found in some file that's included when the script runs, the code will work.

[include()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) and [require()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php) are the commands used to pull in other .php scripts which contain the classes or functions you need. You could write a "header" script which includes all of your dependencies if you like to structure things that way. There are also dependency management tools like [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/) - but these are entirely optional.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think its safe (and even possible? Nah, I'm pretty sure it isn't possible ;) ) to directly communicate with a database from HTML / JavaScript / ... .

Objective - C is a language that has a good MVC pattern. (Model / View / Controller). HTML is a markup - language (VIEW - only). You can call a webservice from this view, (With the aid of AJAX or other..), and that webservice can communicate with a database, and provide you the needed information. ==> Anyhow, there is a need to create a webservice here!

You can also integrate everything in a Web-application. You can build a webapp on  (I like Java, others like .NET, and there are many more...). This is an application that (just like Objective-C) uses an MVC pattern. The HTML page acts as the view, (Storyboard in XCode), you have a controller that builds and fills/returns the view to the user, (just as the ViewControllers).

You should look at both options, depending at what you want to do, both choices work.

I'm happy to help you with further questions or remarks.